# Unable to show correctly symbolic icons with appindicator

Tags: indicator, icons

I'm creating an app under Ubuntu 12.04 and using libappindicator and Vala. I want to use a symbolic icon, to ensure that the colors are adapted to the background in the status bar. Unfortunately, I'm unable to make it work. I installed my icons (which uses the BEBEBE key color) and they are shown, but the color is BEBEBE, not white or black like the other icons.

I also tried to put an icon that I was sure to be symbolic (audio-volume-high-symbolic) but, again, it's shown with the original colors, instead of them being replaced by the current FG color.

I used both **set_icon** and **set_icon_full** methods, but none of them worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by *symbolic icon*.

If you find that your icon does not match the colour scheme of your current theme, then you need to add icons to the relevant directory under `/usr/share/icons` and then run from the terminal `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark` for example.